# SQL date compare

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have a table with 1000 records. One column is the publish date which takes the format `'2008-01-02 00:00:00.000'`. I want to query the SQL DB to get the record with the latest publish date. should i just do a compare or there is some other filter?

Comment: So, is `2008-01-02 00:00:00.000` type `DATETIME` or a `CHAR`?. If its not `DATETIME`, it represents January second or February first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE publishdate = (SELECT MAX(publishdate) FROM tbl)
```

Comment: Thanks, BTW how do i convert this publish date to 'mm/dd/yy' in SQL?

Comment: @javaiText `CONVERT(varchar(8), publishdate, 1)` -- see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 3):

If you want just one record:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM mytable ORDER BY publishdate DESC
```

If you want ALL books with the highest publish date, use Cade Roux's query.

Comment: how do i convert this publish date to 'mm/dd/yy' in SQL?

Comment: See this link on formatting dates, but bear in mind that after you format it, the returned date will actually be a text (varchar) datatype, not  a Date datatype.  A date is what it is, and you can't change how the server stores it, you can only use formatting to tell SQL Server to display it in a certain way.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759292/to-change-date-format-in-sql

Answer (score 0):

If publishdate is datetime

```
SELECT TOP 1  *
FROM tbl
ORDER BY publishdate DESC
```