# Change date format in SQL server express database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to output the date in either `dd/mm/yyyy` or `dd mmm yyyy` e.g. 05/12/2014 or 05 Dec 2014.

```
SELECT [Id]
     , [Name]
     , [Date]
     , [Time] 
FROM [People];
```

Comment: Please take a look at CONVERT function

Comment: You might find some help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17205441/convert-date-format-into-dd-mmm-yyyy-format-in-sql-server-2008  Ideally, output formatting would be done in the technology doing the display.  Are you doing the display within SQL itself, or is there an application on top of it?

Comment: I'm guessing this may have been the first time this question has been asked.  Formatting a date in sql-server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [To change date format in sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759292/to-change-date-format-in-sql)

Comment: @granadaCoder unfortunately not http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759292/to-change-date-format-in-sql?rq=1 , OP should read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask there appears to be no research done on this.

Comment: Thanks @David I actually tried that and couldn't get it to work. It's in a asp.net and c# application. I'm sure there's enough information below to figure it out. I tried many possibilities but no luck. thanks all the same David

Comment: @aazzaawwaazzaa: If you're using .NET then you can just call `.ToString()` on the `DateTime` object and pass it a custom format string: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

A date is a date in the database; you can't change how it's stored.  You need to display the date as text and format it to whatever you need.

```
DECLARE @InputDate DATETIME
SET @InputDate = GETDATE()

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @InputDate, 1) --will display ass dd/mm/yy
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @InputDate, 106) --will display as dd <month abbrev> yyyy
```

See this for reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
  SELECT CONVERT( VARCHAR(10), @date ,106)
```

See [here](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx) fore more formats.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [Id], [Name], [Date], CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[Time],103) FROM [People];
```