# Return Order Date Format Differently

Tags: sql

I am using this query to return the order date and some other information as well.

```
SELECT DISTINCT  
       OrderID, 
       convert(nvarchar(10),OrderDate,101) as OrderDate, 
       SalesmanName, 
       CustomerID, 
       Name, 
       Profile, 
       VehicleMake, 
       VehicleModel 
FROM v_PUSH_ORDERS
```

However the date comes back for example like this:12/19/2014

when I would like it to come back like this 12/19/14

How would I do this?

Comment: Did you take a look at the list of formats on the help page for the `CONVERT` function?

Comment: Obviously minimal research effort. This questions would have taken longer to write up compared to searching for this yourself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [To change date format in sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759292/to-change-date-format-in-sql)

Comment: its not a duplicate and instead of using 10 i used 1 thanks though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),OrderDate,10) as OrderDate
```

Taken from [the very first search result](https://www.google.com/#q=date+format+sql).